# Filter M2M in template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In my model, I have the following M2M field

```
class FamilyMember(AbstractUser):
    ...
    email_list = models.ManyToManyField('EmailList', verbose_name="Email Lists", blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

The EmailList table looks like this:

```
class EmailList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='My List')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Active")
    is_managed_by_user = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="User Managed")
```

In the app, the user should only see records that is_active=True and is_managed_by_user=True.

In the Admin side, the admin should be able to add a user to any/all of these groups, regardless of the is_active and is_managed_by_user flag.

What happens is that the Admin assigns a user to all of the email list records.  Then, the user logs in and can only see a subset of the list (is_active=True and is_managed_by_user=True).   This is expected behavior.   However, what comes next is not.

The user deselects an email list item and then saves the record.   Since M2M_Save first clears all of the m2m records before it calls save() I lose all of the records that the Admin assigned to this user.

How can I keep those? I've tried creating multiple lists and then merging them before the save, I've tried passing the entire list to the template and then hiding the ones where is_managed_by_user=False, and I just can't get anything to work.

What makes this even more tricky for me is that this is all wrapped up in a formset.

How would you go about coding this? What is the right way to do it? Do I filter out the records that the user shouldn't see in my view? If so, how do I merge those missing records before I save any changes that the user makes?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try setting up a model manager in your `models.py` to take care of the filtering. You can then call the filter in your `views.py` like so:

***models.py:***

```
class EmailListQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(is_active=True)
    def managed_by_user(self):
        return self.filter(is_managed_by_user=True)

class EmailListManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return EmailListQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
    def get_active(self):
        return self.get_queryset().active()
    def get_all(self):
        return self.get_queryset().active().managed_by_user()

class EmailList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='My List')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Active")
    is_managed_by_user = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="User Managed")

    objects = EmailListManager()
```

***views.py:***

```
def view(request):
    email = EmailList.objects.get_all()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'email': email})
```

Obviously there is outstanding data incorporated in my example, and you are more than welcome to change the variables/filters according to your needs. However, I hope the above can give you an idea of the possibilities you can try.

In your views you could do `email = EmailList.objects.all().is_active().is_managed_by_user()`, but the loading time will be longer if you have a lot of objects in your database. The model manager is preferred to save memory. Additionally, it is not reliant on what the user does, so both the admin and user interface have to talk to the model directly (keeping them in sync).

*Note: The example above is typed directly into this answer and has not been validated in a text editor. I apologize if there are some syntax or typo errors.*

Comment: (Is it appropriate to edit my original post in response to your answer?)

Comment: I added a manager very similar to what you suggested and it filtered the email list as expected. However, when I make a change it also removes those records that did not fit the filter. It still wiped out the changes that the Admin made to the email list selection. How do I properly post what I've done and what I've seen?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow. What do you mean it wiped out the changes that the Admin made? As for removing the records that did not fit the filter, that means the filter is doing its job. You'll have to refine the filters based on your needs. You can combine as many filters as you please, but try doing them in the manager if possible instead of the view.

Comment: Using your example code (thank you!) what I am trying to do is use the .is_managed_by_user() query to filter the selects for the user.   That works. However, on the admin page the administrator will see all of the items and can select from those. However, any change that the admin makes is cleared the next time the user saves his record. When the user saves a change, how can I first query the DB to find the selections that the Admin made? And how do I add it to the cleaned_data from the user page so that they can be saved?